# Lazy loading images that are appended by appendChild() in javascript/leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, lazy-loading, leaflet, mapbox

I'm working on a website, http://atlantaartmap.com, which uses leaflet/mapbox to plot street art around Atlanta. The image details are read from a geojson file. While leaflet is reading the geojson, I append thumbnails to a nav bar at the bottom that also link to the corresponding map marker. Appending the images instead of hard coding them allows me to update a single file to change all aspects of the page.

I am attempting to use lazy load on these images, but it doesn't seem to work with items that are appended using java script. Any tips?

Here is the lazy version of the page I am testing: http://atlantaartmap.com/lazy.html

Here is the normal version of the site: http://atlantaartmap.com

Thanks in advance.

edit: For clarification, I would like the lazy loading script to avoid loading images until they are within the window.

Comment: You calling the lazyload plugin in a handler that's listening to an event that doesn't exist. Looking through the documentation for [L.mapbox.featureLayer](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.1.4/l-mapbox-featurelayer/) there is no event called `ready`. Also absent in [L.FeatureGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup) and [L.LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) where L.mapbox.featureLayer is extended from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really would suggest that you try [lazySizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes). Different to other lazyloaders it is a self-initializing script, which automatically detects new elements and their visibility. So you don't need to call or configure anything here. Simply append an image with the class `lazyload` and add your source to the `data-src` attribute. That's it:

```
<img src="spinner.gif" data-src="image.jpg" class="lazyload" />
```

Here [is a simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/xx7Lz0jj/embedded/result/).

```js
window.lazySizesConfig = window.lazySizesConfig || {};
window.lazySizesConfig.expand = 40;
window.lazySizesConfig.addClasses = true;

document.querySelector('.add').onclick = function(){
    document.querySelector('.scroll-doc').innerHTML = document.querySelector('.template').innerHTML;
};
```

```css
.scroll-area {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 2px 2px 10px;
}
.scroll-doc {
    display: table;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.scroll-item {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding: 10px;
}
.intrinsic {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 75%;
    height: 0px;
}
.lazyload,
.lazyloading {
    opacity: 0;
}
.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}
.add {
    font-size: large;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://afarkas.github.io/lazysizes/lazysizes.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="add">add to scroll area</button>
<div class="scroll-area">
    <div class="scroll-doc"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/html" class="template">
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/1"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/2"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/3"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/4"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/5"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/6"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/7"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/8"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/animals/9"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/1"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/2"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/3"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/4"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/5"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/6"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/7"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/8"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="scroll-item">
        <div class="intrinsic">
            <img
            class="lazyload"
            data-src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/food/9"
            alt="" />
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, alexander farkas. I am having some trouble with lazy sizes, but I have updated the version at http://atlantaartmap.com/lazy.html . I'm going to keep messing around and checking the examples to see if I can catch what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Boom, got it. For some reason, the js files I was getting from github  were logging errors in the console (something about an unexpected ">"). I replaced them with the file from the demo page. I then had to fiddle around with some of the config options that replace image classes and I eventually got it to work. Thanks again for the help.

This was definitely a learning experience.

Answer (score 3):

I would just throw out the plugin and do that yourself, it's actually very simple to do. You create one image element with your loading image as source, append that as a child to your a (link) element:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = 'images/loading.gif';
link.appendChild(image);
```

Next up you create another image element with your actual image as a source, but you don't need to append it to anything. Just listen for the onload event to fire, then swap the sources:

```
var original = new Image();
original.src = feature.properties.image;
original.onload = function () {
    image.src = original.src;
}
```

That should work like a charm. Now you can leave out jQuery and the plugin so that's two dependency assets less to load, so your page is loading faster also. Win/win situation if you ask me ;)

Here's a example of the concept on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/waud32ta/

Comment: Thanks for the response, iH8. I have a few questions, because I am new to this stuff. Forgive me.

Your code waits for original to load, and then replaces the image object's source with the original's source. What triggers the onload event for image? It seems like it is waiting for the original to load. What I really want to wait is for the loading gif to be view in the viewport. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the code.

Comment: When you use `new Image()` and set the src attribute, javascript immediately starts loading the set src. That always happens, regardless if the element is placed in the DOM or not. The onload event gets fired automaticly once the src is fully loaded. So what this code does is place the loading image directly into the DOM and in the background load the original image, once that's loaded the onload fires at which point it assigns the src of the original to the src of the image that's already placed in the DOM. At that point the image is already fully loaded so it will be directly visible.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It sounds like that might not quite be what I am looking for. What I want to do is avoid loading images that are outside of the window, since there will be a lot of them once the map fills out. It seems as though the script you provided will replace a placeholder image once the desired image is loaded, regardless of whether or not it is in the window. Is that the interpretation correct?

Comment: That's completely correct but as far as i could see it's also what you were doing in your initial code and you did not mention that anywhere in your question so i didn't take that into account. I guess you're better of with the solution of Alexander Farkas. Also if you want something like that i would also recommend not attaching markers which are out of map bounds. Good luck!

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to this, and I thought that lazy loading implied not loading images until they were in view.

Comment: You are absolutely correct, i was mixing up pre with lazyloading, please disregard my latest comment and as i see it now, my entire answer. Sorry for wasting your time. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try calling

```
$("img.navthumb").lazyload();
```

after the thumbnail code has been dynamically injected using JavaScript method appendChild().

Also, i would be able to help you better if you post a JSFiddle.

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help, Hemant. The JS clode can be found [here](http://atlantaartmap.com/lazy_art.js), but I will work on putting together a JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem. The call to lazy load is actually done at the very end of the js file (so it is after the appendChild()). Is there something wrong about the way I am doing it?

Comment: Call lazyload as stated above after,   //populate thumbnail bar
    var link = info.insertBefore(document.createElement('a'),info.firstChild)

Comment: I just updated the website to call the lazy load after the html is appended (also tried right after the element is appended). I don't think it seems to be working. When I test the code on my computer, the python simplehttpserver shows all of the images being requested the minute that the page is loaded.

I also cut the following code out of the end of the script.
`oneArtPlease.on('ready', function() { 
    $("img.navthumb").lazyload();
    });`

Edit: Sometimes it actually seems like it works, but it's unpredictable. The first image also has trouble, which I have seen on other lazy pages.

Comment: Thanks for the response, please post a fiddle so that i can investigate further!

Comment: It will take me some time/fiddling to figure out how jsfiddle works, but I'll post one once it is ready. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so far you have highlighted that jQuery should be [avoided](http://lea.verou.me/2015/04/jquery-considered-harmful/). But I think it's possible to use micro-plugins which contains only the logic you really need. One of them is [justlazy](http://fhopeman.github.io/justlazy/). It's a lazy loading library which has no external dependencies and provides compact image loading code.

**First**, you have to define your placeholders:

```html
<span data-src="path/to/image" data-alt="some alt text"
      data-title="some title"
      class="justlazy-placeholder">
</span>
```

It's also possible to define the placeholder as img-tag to be more SEO friendly. One other feature is the loading of responsive images with srcset attribute.

The **second step** is to initialize the lazy loading via javascript:

```js
Justlazy.registerLazyLoadByClass("justlazy-placeholder"{
    // defines that the image will be loaded
    // 200 pixels before it gets visible
    threshold: 200
});
```